# Custom Input Like Time in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want two inputs called Open from and Close On. There is some issue in time input like time format etc, I want to go with text input. I want my user to input time like 00:00. I want to verify that they have input like this but I don't know how I can achieve this with laravel. My input field like this

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="formrow {!! APFrmErrHelp::hasError($errors, 'open_to') !!}" id="open_to_div"> {!! Form::text('open_to', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'open_to', 'placeholder'=>__('Closed On Like 00:00'))) !!}
             </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if some expert can help me for verify input of my this field.
Thanks

Comment: You can validate input data with front end scripts like j query or from backend side use laravel validator.

Comment: Use the `required` attribute to make sure users entered something. `input` fields also have a `pattern` attribute you can use to make sure they use the correct format

Comment: Or use a timepicker component,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you consider to use bootstrap-timepicker ?
https://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

You can install it running:
**npm i bootstrap-timepicker**

Import it in your **/resources/js/app.js** file with
**import 'bootstrap-timepicker';**

Compile it running:
**npm run dev**

Then:
**$("input[name='your_input_name']").timepicker();**